# Scala UDF function to operate on Array Column and return custom value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have 2 data sets like this

```
val jsonStr ="""{
    
        "TransactionId": 1,
        "TransactionName": "Name",
        "Order": 12, 
        "ReplaceStrings": [
            "UNDEFINED","INVALID"
        ],
        "Country" : "China"           
     
}"""

val configurations = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonStr).toDS)
```

This has all my configurations & filters

```
My Data
val data =  Seq((1,"Mindy","Devaney","mdevaney0@cnbc.com","Female","United States","UTF-8"),(2,"Charmain","Clear","candriolli1@miitbeian.gov.cn","Female","**China**","UTF-8"),(3,"Dilan","**UNDEFINED**","dphilipeaux2@jalbum.net","Male","**China**","Windows-1252")).toDF("id","Fname","LName","mailid","Gender","Country","Codepage" )
```

Now , my ask is to join the configurations data which has filters and retrieve respective results with the above data as the filters are applied on Country China, all the LName which has UNDEFINED as the values to be replaced with an empty string.

I tried putting some UDF to define this as function  but stuck on how to send the json value which is an wrapped array or trying with Seq data type

If someone looked in the similar case or thoughts please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> data.show(false)
+---+--------+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------+------------+
|id |Fname   |LName        |mailid                      |Gender|Country      |Codepage    |
+---+--------+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------+------------+
|1  |Mindy   |Devaney      |mdevaney0@cnbc.com          |Female|United States|UTF-8       |
|2  |Charmain|Clear        |candriolli1@miitbeian.gov.cn|Female|**China**    |UTF-8       |
|3  |Dilan   |**UNDEFINED**|dphilipeaux2@jalbum.net     |Male  |**China**    |Windows-1252|
+---+--------+-------------+----------------------------+------+-------------+------------+
```

```
scala> configurations.show(false)
+-------+-----+--------------------+-------------+---------------+
|Country|Order|ReplaceStrings      |TransactionId|TransactionName|
+-------+-----+--------------------+-------------+---------------+
|China  |12   |[UNDEFINED, INVALID]|1            |Name           |
+-------+-----+--------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

```
scala> val check = udf((lname:String,replaceStrings:Seq[String]) => if(replaceStrings.map(d => s"**${d}**").contains(lname)) "" else lname )
```

```
scala> data.join(configurations,data("Country").contains(configurations("Country")),"inner").withColumn("LName",check($"LName",$"ReplaceStrings")).drop(configurations("Country")).show(false)
+---+--------+-----+----------------------------+------+---------+------------+-----+--------------------+-------------+---------------+
|id |Fname   |LName|mailid                      |Gender|Country  |Codepage    |Order|ReplaceStrings      |TransactionId|TransactionName|
+---+--------+-----+----------------------------+------+---------+------------+-----+--------------------+-------------+---------------+
|2  |Charmain|Clear|candriolli1@miitbeian.gov.cn|Female|**China**|UTF-8       |12   |[UNDEFINED, INVALID]|1            |Name           |
|3  |Dilan   |     |dphilipeaux2@jalbum.net     |Male  |**China**|Windows-1252|12   |[UNDEFINED, INVALID]|1            |Name           |
+---+--------+-----+----------------------------+------+---------+------------+-----+--------------------+-------------+---------------+
```